# Contour/imshow plot for irregular X Y Z data

Tags: python, plot, contour, imshow

I have data in X, Y, Z format where all are 1D arrays, and Z is the amplitude of the measurement at coordinate (X,Y). I'd like to show this data as a contour or 'imshow' plot where the contours/color represent the the value Z (amplitude).

The grid for measurements and X and Y look are irregularly spaced.

Many thanks,

len(X)=100

len(Y)=100

len(Z)=100

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242382/interpolation-over-an-irregular-grid

Comment: have your tried something? you got any errors?

Comment: The other post's focus is mostly on interpolating the irregular data in 2D. I don't need/want interpolation.

Answer (score 61):

Does `plt.tricontourf(x,y,z)` satisfy your requirements?

It will plot filled contours for irregularly spaced data (non-rectilinear grid).

You might also want to look into `plt.tripcolor()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
z = np.sin(x)+np.cos(y)
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax[0].tripcolor(x,y,z)
ax[1].tricontourf(x,y,z, 20) # choose 20 contour levels, just to show how good its interpolation is
ax[1].plot(x,y, 'ko ')
ax[0].plot(x,y, 'ko ')
plt.savefig('test.png')
```

[image: tripcolor and tricontourf example]

Comment: yes indeed, but still the plot is too rough. I am looking into ways to make it looks smoother. Thanks!

Comment: @Scientist, when I use tripcolor and also have it plot the (random) points I generated, I see it cannot be more accurate: a correct triangulation is made, and these patches are then filled based on the values in the nodes of the triangles.

Comment: Oliver, thank you for your input. I will push and see whether I can re-arrange the 1-D arrays so that plt.contour can use it.

Comment: @Scientist, there is no need to rearrange the values for `plt.contour`. Just look at `tricontourf` (shown in the figure) or `tricontour` (if you don't like filled contours).

Comment: Figured a solution: By increasing the "linewidths" option in tricontour, smoothing can be achieved. Cheers...

Comment: @Scientist, the option `linewidths` doesn't make the lines "smoother", it just makes the contourlines thicker. That's not smoothing, but it looks like you have what you need.

Comment: Yes, indeed. it's only a de-facto solution. I couldn't find a way to 'smooth' the overall contours with tricontour.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks, Oliver W.!

Comment: is this command similar to matlab's patch(), where you specify edges and vertex values?

Answer (score 4):

After six years, I may be a little late to the party, but the following extension of [Oliver W.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27004916/4772635) using the Gouraud interpolation might give the 'smooth' result:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1234)  # fix seed for reproducibility
x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
z = np.sin(x)+np.cos(y)
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True, sharey=True, clear=True)
for axes, shading in zip(ax, ['flat', 'gouraud']):
    axes.tripcolor(x,y,z, shading=shading)
    axes.plot(x,y, 'k.')
    axes.set_title(shading)
plt.savefig('shading.png')
```

[comparison between `flat` and `gouraud` shading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEUQE.png)

Comment: This answer does not work for non convex forms :(

Answer (score 2):

(Source code @ the end...)

Here's a little bit of eye candy that I produced playing around with this a bit.  It explores the fact that a linear transformation of a meshgrid is still a meshgrid.  I.e. on the left of all of my plots, I'm working with X and Y coordinates for a 2-d (input) function.  On the right, I want to work with (AVG(X, Y), Y-X) coordinates for the same function.

I played around with making meshgrids in native coordinates and transforming them into meshgrids for the other coordinates.  Works fine if the transform is linear.

For the bottom two graphs, I worked with random sampling to address your question directly.

Here are the images with `setlims=False`:
[image]

And the same with `setlims=True`:
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def f(x, y):
    return y**2 - x**2
lim = 2
xlims = [-lim , lim]
ylims = [-lim, lim]

setlims = False

pde = 1
numpts = 50
numconts = 20

xs_even = np.linspace(*xlims, num=numpts)
ys_even = np.linspace(*ylims, num=numpts)

xs_rand = np.random.uniform(*xlims, size=numpts**2)
ys_rand = np.random.uniform(*ylims, size=numpts**2)

XS_even, YS_even = np.meshgrid(xs_even, ys_even)

levels = np.linspace(np.min(f(XS_even, YS_even)), np.max(f(XS_even, YS_even)), num=numconts)

cmap = sns.blend_palette([sns.xkcd_rgb['cerulean'], sns.xkcd_rgb['purple']], as_cmap=True)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(10, 15))

ax = axes[0, 0]
H = XS_even
V = YS_even
Z = f(XS_even, YS_even)
ax.contour(H, V, Z, levels, cmap=cmap)
ax.plot(H.flatten()[::pde], V.flatten()[::pde], linestyle='None', marker='.', color='.75', alpha=0.5, zorder=1, markersize=4)
if setlims:
    ax.set_xlim([-lim/2., lim/2.])
    ax.set_ylim([-lim/2., lim/2.])
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_title('Points on grid, contour')

ax = axes[1, 0]
H = H.flatten()
V = V.flatten()
Z = Z.flatten()
ax.tricontour(H, V, Z, levels, cmap=cmap)
ax.plot(H.flatten()[::pde], V.flatten()[::pde], linestyle='None', marker='.', color='.75', alpha=0.5, zorder=1, markersize=4)
if setlims:
    ax.set_xlim([-lim/2., lim/2.])
    ax.set_ylim([-lim/2., lim/2.])
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_title('Points on grid, tricontour')

ax = axes[0, 1]
H = (XS_even + YS_even) / 2.
V = YS_even - XS_even
Z = f(XS_even, YS_even)
ax.contour(H, V, Z, levels, cmap=cmap)
ax.plot(H.flatten()[::pde], V.flatten()[::pde], linestyle='None', marker='.', color='.75', alpha=0.5, zorder=1, markersize=4)
if setlims:
    ax.set_xlim([-lim/2., lim/2.])
    ax.set_ylim([-lim, lim])
ax.set_xlabel('AVG')
ax.set_ylabel('DIFF')
ax.set_title('Points on transformed grid, contour')

ax = axes[1, 1]
H = H.flatten()
V = V.flatten()
Z = Z.flatten()
ax.tricontour(H, V, Z, levels, cmap=cmap)
ax.plot(H.flatten()[::pde], V.flatten()[::pde], linestyle='None', marker='.', color='.75', alpha=0.5, zorder=1, markersize=4)
if setlims:
    ax.set_xlim([-lim/2., lim/2.])
    ax.set_ylim([-lim, lim])
ax.set_xlabel('AVG')
ax.set_ylabel('DIFF')
ax.set_title('Points on transformed grid, tricontour')

ax=axes[2, 0]
H = xs_rand
V = ys_rand
Z = f(xs_rand, ys_rand)
ax.tricontour(H, V, Z, levels, cmap=cmap)
ax.plot(H[::pde], V[::pde], linestyle='None', marker='.', color='.75', alpha=0.5, zorder=1, markersize=4)
if setlims:
    ax.set_xlim([-lim/2., lim/2.])
    ax.set_ylim([-lim/2., lim/2.])
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_title('Points random, tricontour')

ax=axes[2, 1]
H = (xs_rand + ys_rand) / 2.
V = ys_rand - xs_rand
Z = f(xs_rand, ys_rand)
ax.tricontour(H, V, Z, levels, cmap=cmap)
ax.plot(H[::pde], V[::pde], linestyle='None', marker='.', color='.75', alpha=0.5, zorder=1, markersize=4)
if setlims:
    ax.set_xlim([-lim/2., lim/2.])
    ax.set_ylim([-lim, lim])
ax.set_xlabel('AVG')
ax.set_ylabel('DIFF')
ax.set_title('Points random transformed, tricontour')

fig.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 1):

Scatter plot may work in your case:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate random data, x,y for coordinates, z for values(amplitude)
x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)
z = np.random.rand(100)

# Scatter plot
plt.scatter(x=x,y=y,c=z)
```

Use the option `c` to visualize your amplitude.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are prepared to deviate from Python into its competitor, R, I have just submitted a package to CRAN (should be available tomorrow or the next day), which conducts contouring on non-regular grids -- the following can be achieved in a few lines of code:

```
library(contoureR)
set.seed(1)
x = runif(100)
y = runif(100)
z = sin(x) + cos(y)
df = getContourLines(x,y,z,binwidth=0.0005)
ggplot(data=df,aes(x,y,group=Group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=z)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red") + 
  theme_bw()
```

Which produces the following:

[image: example]

If you want a more regular grid, and can afford a bit of extra computation time:

```
x = seq(0,1,by=0.005)
y = seq(0,1,by=0.005)
d = expand.grid(x=x,y=y)
d$z = with(d,sin(x) + cos(y))
df = getContourLines(d,binwidth=0.0005)
ggplot(data=df,aes(x,y,group=Group)) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=z)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="blue",high="red") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image: example2]

The fuzzy edges in the above, I know how to resolve and should be fixed for the next version of the software....

Answer (score -1):

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)

plt.contour(xx, yy, z)
```

Doesn't matter if they are irregularly spaced, contour and 3d plots require a meshgrid.

Comment: Z has to be two dimensional in this case. Does not work with 1-D arrays.

Comment: Are you sure you dont want a lines3d plot?  Sounds more like what your data is built for

Comment: positive. I need a contour plot. When I say they are 1-D arrays, I am not saying all elements are sorted and represent a line. x-y make up a nice -irregularly spaced- grid, with each point having a corresponding Z value.

Comment: If Z is 1-D data, it's just not going to work on a contour plot.  By definition, contour pots requre Z values to be a 2d matrix.  Think about it, every value on your contour point has to exist at some x and y point, so it has to be 2d.  But 3 1-d lines can be plotted as lines3d:

http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Otherwise, you're going to need your Z data to be a function of X and Y.

Comment: Ah I see the tricolor plot does work for this data type!

Comment: I don't think so! Although "contour" is set up to accept 2-D arrays only... That's why I raised the issue. "every value on your contour point has to exist at some x and y point", absolutely right, and this can be done with 1-D arrays. Every element in Z, corresponds to the amplitude of the element that has coordinates (X,Y). This can be set up in 2-D, but also in 1-D. 2-D is NOT an absolute must to assign Z values for a grid of X & Y.

Comment: It did indeed, but it is not as versatile as 'contour' and looks very rough/ugly b/c it utilizes a triangulation 'algorithm'.

Comment: Hmm, what if you made Z into a mesh grid by taking it as its own mesh?

IE:

ZZ = np.meshgrid(z, z)

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Let me try!

Comment: Actually, it just occurred to me that if you turn your data into an X,Y matrix where the values are Z, you can also use imshow, not just contours.

Comment: I have been trying to do this. But then, x and y have to be converted into 2D arrays as well. At least for me, this process has not been trivial. Any pointers on how to convert 1-D arrays (x,y,z) into 2D-arrays (X,Y,Z) that can be used with imshow or contour?

Comment: I think the reason you're having this much trouble is because if I understand, you have X and Y coordinates.  Let's say x = 1,2,3,4,5 and y = 1,2,3,4,5.  Most two dimensional data is actually made for a grid, so that your Z(x, y) would not be 5 values, but 5x5 values.  For example, Z(x=1, y=1) = 1, Z(x=1, y=2) ... but your Z data is also 1 dimensional, yes?  If se, what do you think it should look like in 2d?  Maybe take this to the matplotlib mailing list?

Comment: In fact my 1-D arrays look like: x= 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2... and y=1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4... So, indeed the x-y values cover almost the whole grid but not perfectly. That is ok though. There should be a neat pythonic way to plot these as a contour without invoking brute-force for loops.