# Gridded Data Plotting

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

Hi I have a dataset consisting of long, lat and value. This dataset fat for each coordinate of the world a separate row and is therefore a Gridded Data dataset. Now I want to import this from a CSV file into my project and plot it in Basemap (and display it as a Contourf). I have managed the import, but the display of the data as a Contourf still poses problems. For example, I get the error message:

```
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

my code:

```
from traceback import print_tb
import numpy as np
from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
from pykrige.kriging_tools import write_asc_grid
import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Path, PathPatch
import pandas as pd
from numpy import linspace

def load_data():
    df = pd.read_csv(r"File", usecols=['Value'])
    return(df)

 def get_data(df):
    return {
        "lons": df['Longitude'],
        "lats": df['Latitude'],
        "values": df['Value']
     }
def generate_grid(df, basemap, delta=1):
    grid["lon"] = linspace(0, basemap.urcrnrx, df.shape[1])
    grid["lat"] = linspace(0, basemap.urcrnry, df.shape[1])
    grid = {
        'lon': np.arange(-180, 180, delta),
        'lat': np.arange(-89.9,89.9, delta) # dont extrapolate towards the poles
    }
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = np.meshgrid(grid["lon"], grid["lat"])
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = basemap(grid["x"], grid["y"])
    return grid

def prepare_map_plot():
    figure, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
    basemap = Basemap(projection='robin', lon_0=0, lat_0=0, resolution='l',area_thresh=1000000,ax=axes) 
    basemap.drawcoastlines() 
    basemap.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,30.))
    basemap.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,420.,60.))
    return figure, axes, basemap

def plot_mesh_data(df, grid, basemap):
    colormesh = basemap.contourf(grid["x"], grid["y"],df, 32, cmap='RdBu_r', ) #plot the data on the map. plt.cm.RdYlBu_r
    color_bar = basemap.colorbar(colormesh,location='bottom',pad="10%") 

df = load_data()
# print(df['Latitude'].shape)
figure, axes, basemap = prepare_map_plot()
grid = generate_grid(df, basemap, 90)
plot_mesh_data(df, grid,basemap)
# plt.show()
```

But more importantly: how do I manage to display the data, do I have to interpolate it again?

Comment: Not really answering I know but in case you don't know them you might want to take a look at [`cartopy`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/advanced_plotting.html) and maybe [`xarray`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/examples/ERA5-GRIB-example.html) to make everything easier.

Comment: Ok do you have an example for catopy?

Comment: There is a link in the comment with some examples. Basically you just use the good `projection=` when creating the `ax`, and the good `transform=` when plotting on `ax`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contour/imshow plot for irregular X Y Z data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27004422/contour-imshow-plot-for-irregular-x-y-z-data)