# Errors in segmented package: breakpoints confusion

Tags: r, linear-regression

Using the segmented package to create a piecewise linear regression I am seeing an error when I try to set my own breakpoints; it seems only when I try to set more than two.

(EDIT) Here is the code I am using:

```
# data
bullard <- structure(list(Rt = c(0, 4.0054, 25.1858, 27.9998, 35.7259, 39.0769, 
45.1805, 45.6717, 48.3419, 51.5661, 64.1578, 66.828, 111.1613, 
114.2518, 121.8681, 146.0591, 148.8134, 164.6219, 176.522, 177.9578, 
180.8773, 187.1846, 210.5131, 211.483, 230.2598, 262.3549, 266.2318, 
303.3181, 329.4067, 335.0262, 337.8323, 343.1142, 352.2322, 367.8386, 
380.09, 388.5412, 390.4162, 395.6409), Tem = c(15.248, 15.4523, 
16.0761, 16.2013, 16.5914, 16.8777, 17.3545, 17.3877, 17.5307, 
17.7079, 18.4177, 18.575, 19.8261, 19.9731, 20.4074, 21.2622, 
21.4117, 22.1776, 23.4835, 23.6738, 23.9973, 24.4976, 25.7585, 
26.0231, 28.5495, 30.8602, 31.3067, 37.3183, 39.2858, 39.4731, 
39.6756, 39.9271, 40.6634, 42.3641, 43.9158, 44.1891, 44.3563, 
44.5837)), .Names = c("Rt", "Tem"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-38L))

library(segmented)

# create a linear model
out.lm <- lm(Tem ~ Rt, data=bullard)

o<-segmented(out.lm, seg.Z=~Rt, psi=list(Rt=c(200,300)), control=seg.control(display=FALSE))
```

Using the `psi` option, I have tried the following:

```
psi = list(x = c(150, 300)) -- OK
psi = list(x = c(100, 200)) -- OK
psi = list(x = c(200, 300)) -- OK
psi = list(x = c(100, 300)) -- OK
psi = list(x = c(120, 150, 300)) -- error 1 below
psi = list(x = c(120, 300)) -- OK
psi = list(x = c(120, 150)) -- OK
psi = list(x = c(150, 300)) -- OK
psi = list(x = c(100, 200, 300)) -- error 2 below
```

(1) `Error in segmented.lm(out.lm, seg.Z = ~Rt, psi = list(Rt = c(120, 150,  : 
  only 1 datum in an interval: breakpoint(s) at the boundary or too close`

(2) `Error in diag(Cov[id, id]) : subscript out of bounds`

I have already listed my data [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12105435/857416), but as a guide the limits on the x data are about 0--400.

A second question that pertains to this one is: how do I actually fix the breakpoints using this segmented package?

Comment: The data may be in the other question, but can you turn that into a reproducible example, showing exactly the function call you have been trying?

Comment: If you are using `seg.lm.fit` the docs for `PSI` say "appropriate __matrix__ including the starting values of the breakpoints to be estimated"

Comment: Hi sean, thanks for response. i added my code, though I'm not sure how to easily convert my data into script (in-line so to speak), so i left in the read.delim call.

Comment: Maybe you could add the output of dput(head(bullard)) to give a sense of what the data looks like.

Comment: @seancarmody ah that's lovely. thanks, didn't know how to do it. The dataset is small enough to have it all in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here seems to be poor error trapping in the `segmented` package. Having a look at the code for `segmented.lm` allows a bit of debugging. For example, in the case of `psi = list(x = c(100, 200, 300))`, an augmented linear model is fitted as shown below:

```
lm(formula = Tem ~ Rt + U1.Rt + U2.Rt + U3.Rt + psi1.Rt + psi2.Rt + 
    psi3.Rt, data = mf)

Call:
lm(formula = Tem ~ Rt + U1.Rt + U2.Rt + U3.Rt + psi1.Rt + psi2.Rt + 
    psi3.Rt, data = mf)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           Rt        U1.Rt        U2.Rt        U3.Rt      psi1.Rt        
   15.34303      0.04149      0.04591    742.74186   -742.74499      1.02252       
   psi2.Rt      psi3.Rt  
        NA           NA
```

As you can see, the fit has `NA` values which then result in a degenerate variance-covariance matrix (called `Cov` in the code). The function doesn't check for this and tries to pull out diagonal entries from `Cov` and fails with the error message shown. At least the first error, although perhaps not overly helpful, is caught by the function itself and suggests that the break-points are too close.

In the absence of better error trapping in the function, I think that all you can do is adopt a trial and error approach (and avoid break points which are too close). For example, `psi = list(x = c(50, 200, 300))` seems to work ok.

Comment: This error really is frustrating when you know your breakpoints precisely.

Comment: The five year old error seems still to be existing. Funny thing: when I repeat my `segmented()` call, the error somewhen dissapears!

Answer (score 5):

If you use `while` and `tryCatch` you can make the command repeat itself until it decides there is no error in the model @jaySf. I'm guessing this is down to the randomiser settings in the function, which can be seen in `seg.control`.

```
lm.model <- lm(xdat ~ ydat, data = x)
if.false <- F
while(if.false == F){
  tryCatch({
    s <- segmented(lm.model, seg.Z =~ydata, psi = NA)
    if.false <- T
  }, error = function(e){
  }, finally = {})
}
```

Comment: There is a risk this runs forever, any way to try only a hundred times and then give up?

Comment: You may add a loop index, such as:

lm.model <- lm(xdat ~ ydat, data = x)

if.false <- F
idx <- 1L
while(if.false == F & idx <= 100L){
  tryCatch({
    s <- segmented(lm.model, seg.Z =~ydata, psi = NA)
    if.false <- T
  }, error = function(e){
  }, finally = {})

  idx <- idx + 1L
}