# n-dim python interpolation nonlinear

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

i got a function of 5 variables Fx(s,m,p,h,l)

```
import numpy as np
s= np.arange(0,135,15)/10
m= np.array([150,180,195,210,240,255,270,285,300])
p=np.array([-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5])
h=np.array([0,3,6,9,12])
l=np.array([0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,4])
```

and 180 values of the function in a csv file. 
i would like to calculate missing value by interpolation in all points
and use radial basis function thin_plate will by great. is it possible?
for information i found here 
[Python 4D linear interpolation on a rectangular grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119892/python-4d-linear-interpolation-on-a-rectangular-grid)
InterpolatingFunction
but if i replace some value in data array by None, at this point f(point) give 'nan'. and i don t want to use a linear interpolation because for a set of 4 variables i got 2 points with a value.
thanks very much for helping LL

Answer (score 0):

Try SVR from [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) to solve your problem:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR # it uses RBF as default kernel
import numpy as np

n_samples, n_features = 180, 5

y = np.random.randn(n_samples)  #function values
X = np.random.randn(n_samples, n_features)   #points
clf = SVR(C=1.0, epsilon=0.2)
clf.fit(X, y)

#Get value at a new point:

clf.predict([0,150,-1.5,0,0])
```

Because of len(s)*len(m)*len(p)*len(h)*len(l)  is 22680 and function values are known only in 180 points,  you have poor information about your function....

Comment: hi, thank you a lot, it work, but how can i fix parameters to make the function going exactly through my given values at points ???

Comment: it work perfectly, with C=100000 the function going very close to my given values. but i can't find, how to give more weight to just certain variables like v or m for example?