# Python multidimensional Lookup interpolation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, interpolation, lookup-tables

To interpolate within a dataset, I want to create a multidimensional Lookup table in python. In this case, the tree input arrays x,y and z are given together with the output quantity a.

I was able to visualize the impact of x and y with a 2D heatmap:

```
xi = np.linspace(np.amin(x),np.amax(x),100)
yi = np.linspace(np.amin(y),np.amax(y),100)

zi = griddata((x, y), a, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='linear')

CS = plt.contour(xi,yi,zi,15,linewidths=0.5,colors='k')
CS = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi,15,cmap=plt.cm.bwr_r)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: 2D heatmap]

However, my goal is not visualization. In the end I want to pass some x,y and z values to the Lookup and get an interpolated value of a.

I've already found something related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119892/python-4d-linear-interpolation-on-a-rectangular-grid), but the proposed function did not work. Is there any library I've missed so far or a suitable way to perform a multidimensional interpolation?

Comment: Are your data on any kind of regular grid?

Comment: Yes the data values are within equal ranges per axis.

Comment: That’s not enough—are they a cloud, or are they arranged into complete lines and planes?