# N-Dimensional linear Interpolation in Python (evaluate array using rationale index)

Tags: python, interpolation

Lets assume I have an N-dimensional array `ar` with `ar.shape=(n1,...,nN)`. Is there a python module which allows to evaluate `ar` at an rationale index?

As an example, lets assume: `ar.shape=(3,4,5)`. Then I'm looking for a function `f` that does this: `result=f(ar,[2.3,1.5,3.4])`

Comment: Either you did not explain what you want to do clearly, or your question does not make sense at all. Array have integer indexes. Saying `A[1.3]` does not make sense. Could you provide an example of input *and* expected output?

Comment: What I want, is to evaluate the array at intermediate points. So the function I'm looking for needs to do some kind of interpolation. For the given example of [2.3,1.5,3.4] it would look for the nearest 2^3 neighbors and perform a linear interpolation. Lower positions would be [2,1,3] and upper ones would be [3,2,4]. Does that make sense dfor you?

Answer (score 3):

From the scipy docs: `scipy.interpolate.griddata`: [Interpolate unstructured N-dimensional data](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata).

Comment: I found that one, but I guess that I might be to slow. I already have my data in a structured form and finding the nearest neighbors is easy  and almost trivial.

Comment: @Andre Did you profile it? If not, I'd suggest you to do so. Often using numpy/scipy native functions is much faster than anything you can write in pure-python(even though theoretically it should have a lower asymptotic complexity).

Comment: @ev-br - i have an unstructured 3d array and i need to interpolate to a Cartesian 3d grid with specific grid spacing. Will this work ?

Answer (score 2):

[scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates.html) is fast and easy;
see the clear 2d example under 
[multivariate-spline-interpolation-in-python-scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238250/multivariate-spline-interpolation-in-python-scipy).

(`map_coordinates( ... order=1 )` is what you ask for —
[Bilinear_interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation) in 2d, trilinear in 3d ...
`order=0` is nearest grid point, `order=2` or 3 look at (order+1)^d points — slower and smoother.)

Added: as you probably know, numpy rounds float indices down to ints:

```
A = np.eye( 3 )
print A[ 0.1, 0.9 ], A[ 1.1, 2.9 ]
```