# Fitting 2D data with python

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

I have a set of tabulated data of the form (x,y,z) with z = f(x) + g(y) and the form of f, g is unknown. I would like to perform a simultaneous interpolation for f(x) and g(y), ideally using splines of some order. Is there any existing package to do this in Python? Apologies in advance if this has been already posted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see here to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Hi there, I am interested in learning if someone knows some package which does this. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Johnny, this is not the place to ask this kind of question, have a look on the tour section!   By the way by simply googling fitting python on google yu will find your answer (numpy, scipy, scikit, etc..)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. I will stop here then. Just for reference,  I cannot see the difference between my question and numerous similar posts, e.g here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238250/multivariate-spline-interpolation-in-python-scipy